How to create LazyColumn with both draggable and non-draggable titles and dividers?
I found an example of simple lazy lists with draggable items and tried to modify it to suit my needs. I need to be able to list the indices of the elements on which dragging doesn't work and, if there are any, the dividers don't drag either.
private val standardDpSize = 8.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun <T> DraggableLazyColumn(
    itemsMap: Map<T, @Composable () -> Unit>,
    itemsIndexesOrder: SnapshotStateList<T>,
    dragIgnoredIndexes: List<Int> = emptyList(),
    ignoredItemsMap: Map<Int, @Composable () -> Unit> = emptyMap(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    scope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope(),
    dragIsEnable: Boolean = true
) {
    val dragDropState = rememberDragDropState(
        lazyListState = state,
        ignoredIndexes = dragIgnoredIndexes
    ) { fromIndex, toIndex ->
        itemsIndexesOrder.apply { add(toIndex, removeAt(fromIndex)) }
    }
    var overscrollJob by remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null) }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(dragIsEnable, dragDropState) {
                if (dragIsEnable) detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
                    onDrag = { change, offset ->
                        change.consume()
                        dragDropState.onDrag(offset = offset)

                        if (overscrollJob?.isActive == true) return@detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress

                        dragDropState
                            .checkForOverScroll()
                            .takeIf { it != 0f }
                            ?.let {
                                overscrollJob = scope.launch {
                                    dragDropState.state.animateScrollBy(
                                        it * 1.3f, tween(easing = FastOutLinearInEasing)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                            ?: run { overscrollJob?.cancel() }
                    },
                    onDragStart = { offset ->
                        dragDropState.onDragStart(offset)
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        dragDropState.onDragInterrupted()
                        overscrollJob?.cancel()
                    },
                    onDragCancel = {
                        dragDropState.onDragInterrupted()
                        overscrollJob?.cancel()
                    }
                )
            },
        state = state
    ) {
        if (dragIgnoredIndexes.isNotEmpty()) {
            var ignoredIndex = 0
            var offset = 0
            itemsIndexesOrder.forEachIndexed { index, order ->
                fun item(content: @Composable () -> Unit) = this.item {
                    DraggableItem(
                        dragDropState = dragDropState,
                        index = index + ignoredIndex + offset,
                        modifier = Modifier
                    ) { content() }
                }

                var prevIgnored = false
                while (dragIgnoredIndexes.size > ignoredIndex && index + ignoredIndex == dragIgnoredIndexes[ignoredIndex]) {
                    prevIgnored = true
                    ignoredItemsMap[index + ignoredIndex]?.let { item { it() } }
                    ignoredIndex++
                }
                if (index != 0 && !prevIgnored) {
                    item {
                        HorizontalDivider(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = standardDpSize),
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                        )
                    }
                    offset++
                }
                item { itemsMap[order]!!() }
            }
        } else {
            var offset = 0
            itemsIndexesOrder.forEachIndexed { index, order ->
                if (index != 0) item {
                    HorizontalDivider(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = standardDpSize),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    )
                    offset++
                }
                item { itemsMap[order]!!() }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun rememberDragDropState(
    lazyListState: LazyListState,
    ignoredIndexes: List<Int> = emptyList(),
    hasDividers: Boolean = true,
    onSwap: (Int, Int) -> Unit
): DragDropState {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val state = remember(lazyListState) {
        DragDropState(
            state = lazyListState,
            hasDividers = hasDividers,
            onSwap = onSwap,
            ignoredIndexes = ignoredIndexes,
            scope = scope
        )
    }
    return state
}

private fun LazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex: Int) = layoutInfo
    .visibleItemsInfo
    .getOrNull(absoluteIndex - layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.first().index)

private val LazyListItemInfo.offsetEnd
    get() = offset + size

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
private fun LazyItemScope.DraggableItem(
    dragDropState: DragDropState,
    index: Int,
    modifier: Modifier,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.(isDragging: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val current by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = dragDropState.draggingItemOffset * 0.67f,
        label = "Current item animation"
    )
    val previous by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = dragDropState.previousItemOffset.value * 0.67f,
        label = "Previous item animation"
    )
    val dragging = index == dragDropState.currentIndexOfDraggedItem
    val draggingModifier = when {
        dragging -> {
            Modifier
                .zIndex(1f)
                .graphicsLayer { translationY = current }
        }

        index == dragDropState.previousIndexOfDraggedItem -> {
            Modifier
                .zIndex(1f)
                .graphicsLayer { translationY = previous }
        }

        else -> {
            Modifier.animateItemPlacement(animationSpec = tween(easing = FastOutLinearInEasing))
        }
    }
    Column(modifier = modifier.then(draggingModifier)) {
        content(dragging)
    }
}

private class DragDropState(
    val state: LazyListState,
    private val hasDividers: Boolean = true,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val ignoredIndexes: List<Int> = listOf(),
    private val onSwap: (Int, Int) -> Unit
) {
    private var draggedDistance by mutableFloatStateOf(value = ZERO_FLOAT)
    private var draggingItemInitialOffset by mutableIntStateOf(value = ZERO)
    val draggingItemOffset
        get() = draggingItemLayoutInfo?.let { item ->
            draggingItemInitialOffset + draggedDistance - item.offset
        } ?: ZERO_FLOAT
    private val draggingItemLayoutInfo
        get() = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { it.index == currentIndexOfDraggedItem }

    var previousIndexOfDraggedItem by mutableStateOf<Int?>(value = null)
        private set
    var previousItemOffset = Animatable(initialValue = ZERO_FLOAT)
        private set

    // used to obtain initial offsets on drag start
    private var initiallyDraggedElement by mutableStateOf<LazyListItemInfo?>(value = null)

    var currentIndexOfDraggedItem by mutableStateOf<Int?>(value = null)

    private val initialOffsets
        get() = initiallyDraggedElement?.let { it.offset to it.offsetEnd }

    private val currentElement
        get() = currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let {
            state.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex = it)
        }


    fun onDragStart(offset: Offset) {
        state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { item -> offset.y.toInt() in item.offset..(item.offset + item.size) }
            ?.also {
                currentIndexOfDraggedItem = it.index
                initiallyDraggedElement = it
                draggingItemInitialOffset = it.offset
            }
    }

    fun onDragInterrupted() {
        if (currentIndexOfDraggedItem != null) {
            previousIndexOfDraggedItem = currentIndexOfDraggedItem
            val startOffset = draggingItemOffset
            scope.launch {
                previousItemOffset.snapTo(startOffset)
                previousItemOffset.animateTo(
                    ZERO_FLOAT,
                    tween(easing = FastOutLinearInEasing)
                )
                previousIndexOfDraggedItem = null
            }
        }
        draggingItemInitialOffset = ZERO
        draggedDistance = ZERO_FLOAT
        currentIndexOfDraggedItem = null
        initiallyDraggedElement = null
    }

    fun onDrag(offset: Offset) {
        draggedDistance += offset.y

        initialOffsets?.let { (topOffset, bottomOffset) ->
            val startOffset = topOffset + draggedDistance
            val endOffset = bottomOffset + draggedDistance

            currentElement?.let { hovered ->
                state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                    .filterNot { item ->
                        item.offsetEnd < startOffset || item.offset > endOffset || hovered.index == item.index
                    }
                    .firstOrNull { item ->
                        val delta = (startOffset - hovered.offset)
                        when {
                            delta > ZERO -> (endOffset > item.offsetEnd)
                            else -> (startOffset < item.offset)
                        }
                    }
                    ?.also { item ->
                        val indexAnalyzeResult = item.index.analyze
                        if (!(indexAnalyzeResult.isDivider || indexAnalyzeResult.isIgnored)) {
                            val new = item.index - indexAnalyzeResult.run { skippedElements + dividers }
                            currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let { current ->
                                scope.launch {
                                    onSwap(current.withoutSkippedIndexes, new)
                                }
                            }
                            currentIndexOfDraggedItem = item.index
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private data class ItemIndexAnalyzeResult(
        val skippedElements: Int,
        val dividers: Int,
        val isIgnored: Boolean,
        val isDivider: Boolean
    )

    private val Int.analyze: ItemIndexAnalyzeResult
        get() {
            var skipped = ZERO
            var dividers = ZERO
            var prevIgnored = -1
            var isDivider = false
            var isIgnored = false

            if (ignoredIndexes.isEmpty()) {
                if (hasDividers) {
                    dividers += this / 2
                    isDivider = this % 2 != ZERO
                }
            } else {
                var index = 0
                var lastColumnIgnoredIndex: Int? = null
                while (index < ignoredIndexes.size) {
                    val currentIgnored = ignoredIndexes[index++]
                    val columnIgnoredIndex = currentIgnored + dividers
                    isIgnored = isIgnored || columnIgnoredIndex == this
                    if (columnIgnoredIndex < this) {
                        skipped++
                        if (hasDividers) {
                            if (index == ignoredIndexes.size) lastColumnIgnoredIndex = currentIgnored
                            dividers += (currentIgnored - prevIgnored) / 2
                            prevIgnored = currentIgnored
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (hasDividers) {
                            lastColumnIgnoredIndex = null
                            val offsetItemsWithDividers = (this - prevIgnored - dividers - 1)
                            dividers += offsetItemsWithDividers / 2
                            isDivider = offsetItemsWithDividers % 2 != ZERO
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (hasDividers) lastColumnIgnoredIndex?.let {
                    val offsetItemsWithDividers = (this - it - dividers - 1)
                    dividers += offsetItemsWithDividers / 2
                    isDivider = offsetItemsWithDividers % 2 != ZERO
                }
            }
            val result = ItemIndexAnalyzeResult(
                skippedElements = skipped,
                dividers = dividers,
                isIgnored = isIgnored,
                isDivider = isDivider
            )
            return result
        }

    private val Int.withoutSkippedIndexes
        get() = this - analyze.run { skippedElements + dividers }

    fun checkForOverScroll() = initiallyDraggedElement?.let {
        val startOffset = it.offset + draggedDistance
        val endOffset = it.offsetEnd + draggedDistance
        when {
            draggedDistance > ZERO -> (endOffset - state.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + 50f).takeIf { diff -> diff > ZERO }
            draggedDistance < ZERO -> (startOffset - state.layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset - 50f).takeIf { diff -> diff < ZERO }
            else -> null
        }
    } ?: ZERO_FLOAT

    private companion object {
        const val ZERO = 0
        const val ZERO_FLOAT = 0f
    }
}

I fixed all the problems with indexes, but the animation is terrible: only the last element is processed correctly, and the further away from it, the greater the difference between the element being moved and the element being animated. Can you help me find the error? Or perhaps you already have a solution.
In the future I would like to add the ability to remove elements by swiping, but this is optional. There are analyze and withoutSkippedIndexes with my solution of skipping divideres and titles. I need something like this where only items are draggable:
# Title 0
Item 0
---(Divider)
Item 1
# Title 1
Item 2
# Title 2
Item 3
---(Divider)
Item 4
---(Divider)
etc.

And this is an example of how I use it with preview. I did not customize the color scheme of the component, so the separator colors may not be very convenient.
@Composable
fun Example(modifier: Modifier) {
    @Composable
    fun TitleText(text: String) = Text(text = text, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)

    @Composable
    fun BodyText(text: String) = Text(text = text, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium)

    fun <T> Iterable<Int>.toMap(
        titleText: Boolean = false,
        transform: (Int) -> T
    ): Map<T, @Composable () -> Unit> =
        mutableMapOf<T, @Composable () -> Unit>().apply {
            val toComposable: (Int) -> @Composable () -> Unit = if (titleText) { value: Int ->
                { TitleText(text = "Title $value") }
            } else { value: Int ->
                { BodyText(text = "Item $value") }
            }

            this@toMap.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                put(key = transform(item), value = toComposable(index))
            }
        }

    val itemsMap = IntRange(0, 9).toMap { it.toByte() }
    val dragIgnoredIndexes = listOf(0, 2, 7)
    val ignoredItemsMap = dragIgnoredIndexes.toMap(titleText = true) { it }
    val itemsIndexesOrder = rememberSaveable(
        saver = listSaver(
            save = { it },
            restore = { SnapshotStateList<Byte>().apply { addAll(elements = it) } }
        )
    ) { mutableStateListOf<Byte>().apply { addAll(elements = itemsMap.keys.sorted()) } }
    DraggableLazyColumn(
        itemsMap = itemsMap,
        itemsIndexesOrder = itemsIndexesOrder,
        dragIgnoredIndexes = dragIgnoredIndexes,
        ignoredItemsMap = ignoredItemsMap,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun ExamplePreview() {
    MyTheme {
        Example(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
    }
}


Google provided a demo for having draggable items inside of lazyColumn, that might help you, please check this out:

Just note that it's a sample without a sticky section/header in between but I tried with a divider.

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/LazyColumnDragAndDropDemo.kt


This is just an example that I modified. I need more complex behavior, which is what is written in the question.
